# Editable Datatables PHP MySQL jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have a table which is fed dynamically from the database, this works as it should, I've then put the datatables functionality on the top which is working well, the sorting, search, the pagination is again working as it should.

I'm now looking at being able to edit a row and update the data back into the db and refresh the table.

My table structure

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="tobebookedtable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="display:none;">PropID</th>
        <th>ProjectNo</th>
        <th>Householder</th>
        <th>HouseNoName</th>
        <th>Street Name</th>
        <th>Postcode</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>EPCPlanned</th>
        <th>TAM</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php
            $planning = db::getInstance()->query('CALL sp_tobebooked()');
            foreach ($planning->results() as $planning) {
        ?>
        <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $planning->PropID; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->ProjectNo; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->Householder; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->HouseNoName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->StreetName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->Postcode; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->Telephone; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->EPCPlanned; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->TAM; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The EPCPlanned is the only field I want to update.

This here is my code for the jQuery side, the edit ability works, I can click into a cell and edit the record.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#tobebookedtable').dataTable( {
        //"bProcessing": true,
        //"bServerSide": true,
        //"bJQueryUI": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bStateSave": true
    } );

    /* Init DataTables */
    var oTable = $('#tobebookedtable').dataTable();

    /* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
    oTable.$('td').editable( 'tobebooked_edit.php', {
        "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
            var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
            oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
            //window.location.reload();
        },
        "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
            console.log(value);
            console.log(settings);
            return {
                "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                "column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
            };
        },
        "height": "26px",
        "width": "100%"
    } );    
   } );
  </script>
```

this is the tobebooked_edit.php

```
<?php 
require 'core/init.php';

    $table="temp_tobebooked";
$rawdata    = $_POST;
$query      = "show columns from $table";
$result= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$fields     = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
            $fieldname = $row['Field'];
            array_push($fields, $fieldname);
}

$id             = $rawdata['row_id'];
$value          = $rawdata['value'];
$column         = $rawdata['column'];
$column         = $column + 1;
$fieldname      = $fields[$column];
$value = utf8_decode($value);

$query  = "update $table set $fieldname = '$value' where PropID = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) { echo "Update failed"; }
else          { echo "UPD: $value"; }
?>
```

When it all runs and I update a record the field Updates on the screen and shows with the "UPD:" and the entered value.

But when I check my database there is no record updated. No errors show either

How can I get the data to update in my db?

Comment: First, `mysql_` functions are deprecated and will stop working in a future release of PHP, so use PDO. Second, you need to call the `execute` function rather than `query`.

Comment: try using `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())` to see what error is being thrown.

Comment: Yes I know I should be using PDO, but I wanted to get it working with mysql_ first as this was the quickest way for me to test it working. My plan is once it all works to then convert it to PDO

Comment: @GeoffChapman thanks, I added that in, it showed an error where I forgot to code the table as to where the data is shown from. After adding this in, it still shows as UPD and my updated value but no update in the db table

Comment: have you tried running it after the update query as well?

Comment: @GeoffChapman I added in the `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())` to the updated value, when the page ran it didn't show any errors. I then decided to just look at how tobebooked_edit.php works, I changed the variables to static values and found that a reason was that the header names for my table don't match the field name within the database, I changed them so they matched and the value updated in the database. Putting the table back on I made that the same as the db table also. Tried again and it doesn't still update.

Comment: Is there something within the jQuery that isn't sending the data through to the php page? also is there a way to set the table header to be an alias name of the database table fieldname?

Comment: I don't know the Jeditable but the first test would to be simply dump out the post data in tobebooked_edit.php `var_dump($_POST)` just make sure you remove this once tested.

Comment: This is the result of adding `var_dump($_POST);` `array(3) {  ["value"]=&gt;  string(10) "14/06/2014"  ["id"]=&gt;  string(0) ""  ["row_id"]=&gt;  string(0) ""}UPD: 14/06/2014` It shows the output of the Planned Date I input through the edit cell. I see the problem is that the ID isn't being pulled into the $_POST, now is the fact I have hidden this field having this affect or should that not be a problem? I changed this line in the jQuery to see if it had an affect also, `"row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('PropID'),` the PropID was originally id, but this didn't matter either

Comment: Could you show us a row from your table, as it might be down to the way you're traversing the tree.

Comment: @GeoffChapman I've updated the original post to include my table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think that this

```
<tr>
    <?php
        $planning = db::getInstance()->query('CALL sp_tobebooked()');
        foreach ($planning->results() as $planning) {
    ?>
```

should be

```
<?php
        $planning = db::getInstance()->query('CALL sp_tobebooked()');
        foreach ($planning->results() as $planning) {
    ?>

<tr>
```

Then, with

```
"row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
```

for each *td* element, you select the *tr* element and search for the id attribute, that doesn't exists

Comment: Thanks for the reply, using the `var_dump($_POST);` this is the output from when I enter a date within the EPCPlanned field `array(3) {  ["value"]=&gt;  string(10) "14/06/2014"  ["id"]=&gt;  string(0) ""  ["row_id"]=&gt;  string(0) ""}UPD: 14/06/2014` the "id" or "row_id" don't get the ID assigned to it

Answer (score 1):

Firstly as per rsella's comment you nee to move the row  inside the loop.
Secondly as suspected you are holding the ID in a hidden cell which is infact a sibling of the editable elements rather than the parent. Try changing the table structure to the following

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    $planning = db::getInstance()->query('CALL sp_tobebooked()');
    foreach ($planning->results() as $planning) {
    ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo $planning->PropID; ?>" >
        <td><?php echo $planning->ProjectNo; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->Householder; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->HouseNoName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->StreetName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->Postcode; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->Telephone; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->EPCPlanned; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->TAM; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php };
    ?>
</tbody>
```

This should mean that the parent has an ID and thus `this.parentNode.getAttribute('id')` should be able returning the required value.

As you're only editing the EPCPlanned cell then an alternative would be

```
<tbody>  
    <?php
    $planning = db::getInstance()->query('CALL sp_tobebooked()');
    foreach ($planning->results() as $planning) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $planning->ProjectNo; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->Householder; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->HouseNoName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->StreetName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->Postcode; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->Telephone; ?></td>
        <td id="<?php echo $planning->PropID; ?>"><?php echo $planning->EPCPlanned; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $planning->TAM; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php };
    ?>
</tbody>
```

and in your JQuery change `"row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id')` to `this.getAttribute('id')`

Comment: Superb stuff, this has worked a treat. I went with your second option, I've hidden the PropID from the table header and now when I input the date into EPCPlanned it also shows the PropID in the `var_dump($_POST);` after taking this out, testing on the database it does exactly what you said it would do. Thank you for all your help, I've learnt a number of new things with this.